# Can I switch to an activity in a JAR by JNI

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

I have a JAR which included an activity. If I use JNI, can I switch to that activity from my Android APP?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JNI to launch the activity as long as it is defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml` you should be able to launch with its fully classified name like:

```
StartActivity(
    new Intent(this,
               Java.Lang.Class.ForName("my.awesome.packagename.MyJavaActivity")));
```

Comment: Thanks Cheesebaron for your answer. According to your solution will I have to create a Java Binding Library for the JAR after that add referent from my project? (I create Java Binding Library by Android Java Bindings Library project's template). If yes then I can not do like that. I can not create the Java Binding Library from my JAR because I alway get ton of errors in building progress. Do you know any way to launch the activity via JNI?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this question for myself. Via JNI I create an instance of Activity, after that I register the Activity in Manifest file. In addition, I also pass some parameters to Activity in JAR.

Comment: An example on how you did this would be great, for others who run into the same issue in the future.